# How to restore language settings in Windows from a saved file using a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I need to create a PowerShell script which will restore language settings and input methods (important) from a file. At first I thought it would be easy to use `Get-WinUserLanguageList | Export-CliXML ./mylist.xml` to save current settings and then `$List = Import-CliXML ./mylist.xml`, `Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $List`, however it does not work because the data imported from XML into the variable is deserialized and I get an exception:

Set-WinUserLanguageList : Cannot bind parameter 'LanguageList'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage" value of type 
"Deserialized.Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage" to type 
"Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage".

I've tried using XML but failed, so I created a workaround which looks like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
      [switch]$GenerateList 
      )

function Generate-List { # Generates language files to restore from.
    $GoodList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
    [string[]]$LanguageTags = $GoodList.LanguageTag
    $LanguageTags | Out-File .\LanguageTags.txt
    [string[]]$InputMethods = $GoodList.InputMethodTips
    $InputMethods | Out-File .\InputMethods.txt
    } # Exporting languages and corresponding input methods in separate files. Can be improved.

if ($GenerateList -eq $true) {
    Generate-List
    } # Invokes a function based on a switch parameter.

function RestoreFrom-List {
$GoodList = Get-WinUserLanguageList # Make our variable of a proper type
$GoodList.Clear() # Clear the variable contents
[string[]]$LanguageTags = Get-Content .\LanguageTags.txt
[string[]]$InputMethods = Get-Content .\InputMethods.txt
foreach ($language in $LanguageTags) { # This loop fills $GoodList with proper values
    $index = $LanguageTags.IndexOf($language)
    $GoodList.Add($language) # Add a language to the list
    $GoodList[$index].InputMethodTips.Clear() # Remove default input method
    $GoodList[$index].InputMethodTips.Add($InputMethods[$index]) # Add an input method from a corresponding position in the saved txt file
    }
Set-WinUserLanguageList $GoodList -force # Restore system languages and input methods using a freshly created list
    }

RestoreFrom-List
```

I am new to PowerShell and I am sure this code is ugly and can be improved. Also, it feels that *-WinUserLanguageList cmdlets are a pain to work with - you have to use internal methods to change data instead of the universal `Set-Property`.

So far my script successfully exports language/input-method settings into two(!) txt(!!) files and doesn't work if a particular language has two or more input methods (because it dumps input methods into an array without relating them to a particular language and then retrieves them based on an index). Please help improving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to revisit my old question and post an improved version of the script which uses JSON to store exported languages. Any number of languages and input methods is supported now, and they are stored as a properly structured JSON file. Handwriting and spellchecking settings are also preserved.

```
# Exports/imports windows language settings to/from a file
function ImportExport-Languages {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
          [switch]$GenerateList,
          [string]$Path 
          )

    ## Export
    function Export-Lang {
        Get-WinUserLanguageList | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $Path
    }

    ## Import
    function Import-Lang {
        $importedFile = Get-Content $Path | ConvertFrom-Json
        $langCollection = New-Object Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage[] ""

        foreach ($item in $importedFile)
        {
            $lang = [Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]::new($item.LanguageTag)
            $lang.InputMethodTips.Clear() # clear default auto-generated input method
            foreach ($inputMethod in $item.InputMethodTips)
            {
                $lang.InputMethodTips.Add($inputMethod)
            }
            $lang.Handwriting = $item.Handwriting
            $lang.Spellchecking = $item.Spellchecking
            $langCollection += $lang
        }
        Set-WinUserLanguageList $langCollection -Force
    }

    ## Run
    if ($GenerateList) { Export-Lang }
    Import-Lang
}

ImportExport-Languages -Path "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.json" -GenerateList
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I modified it a little bit because it was not working on windows 10 pro. Changed the array to list of languages now works like a charm.

```
function ImportExport-Languages {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
          [switch]$GenerateList,
          [string]$Path 
          )

    ## Export
    function Export-Lang {
        Get-WinUserLanguageList | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $Path
    }

    ## Import
    function Import-Lang {
        $importedFile = Get-Content $Path | ConvertFrom-Json  
        $langCollection = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]
        
        foreach ($item in $importedFile)
        {
            $lang = [Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]::new($item.LanguageTag)
            $lang.InputMethodTips.Clear() # clear default auto-generated input method
            foreach ($inputMethod in $item.InputMethodTips)
            {
                $lang.InputMethodTips.Add($inputMethod)
            }
            $lang.Handwriting = $item.Handwriting
            $lang.Spellchecking = $item.Spellchecking
            $langCollection.Add($lang)
        }
        Set-WinUserLanguageList $langCollection -Force
    }

    ## Run
    if ($GenerateList) { Export-Lang }
    Import-Lang
}

# usage export ImportExport-Languages -Path "C:\Install\languageExport.json" -GenerateList
# usage import ImportExport-Languages -Path "C:\Install\languageExport.json"
```